# How to retrieve the cakephp used query in find or read

Tags: cakephp

Usually we check the find operation by checking the sql-dump. But it is not possible if query operation done through ajax. How can we check any find operation whick cakePhp done in backgoround and Any way to print it in pr()?

Answer (score 0):

If you give `$this->layout='ajax'` in the controller code, then it would not show the query.So if you want to view the query , just set the layout to your normal layout (only for testing) and check the query and then revert the code.

Comment: Any other way to print query corresponding find?

Answer (score 0):

So for finding queries you have to follow these steps

1- Now go to cake folder and find this path  **cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php**

2- find the function **_execute**. This function is responsible for all the queries what cakephp execute from its functions.

3- debug the $sql variable like

```
function _execute($sql) {
            echo $sql;
        return mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    }
```

4- die the code after the cakephp background retrieval functions. like

```
$referral = $this->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('Referral.id' => $id)
        ));
die();
```

5- If this is ajax call for that you can view the queries in firebug.

*Note: The last displayed query will be your desire query before die*