# How to retrieve insert query used in save() function

Tags: cakephp

The following data I have to insert using save(). The data is from html table.

```
Array
(
[Test] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [patient_id] => 58
                [dt_test] => 2012-06-04
                [name] => dfg
                [result] => 34
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [patient_id] => 58
                [dt_test] => 2012-06-18
                [name] => dsfg
                [result] => 76
            )

    )
```

)
The id is the primary key of 'test'

There is no validation error. But not any row is inserting into the table 'test'.
How can I check the sql query used to insert the data. My db is postgres and version is 1.3

Comment: this is for finding queries for mysql, u can use same apporach for postgres http://stackoverflow.com/a/10683332/1239506

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see queries you need to enable debug mode. In **/cakephp/app/config/core.php** you have to set debug level:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

then you can print all queries by putting this code in your view file:

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

If you prefer to display them from controller, then put this line after save():

```
debug($this->Test->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false));
```